# ROS2, TypeError when publishing custom message to Topic

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have defined a custom message:

```
uint8[] data
```

The custom message is imported in my Node class with no problems:

```
from my_shared.msg import MyMessage
```

In the same Node, I create the publisher with:

```
self.my_publisher = self.create_publisher(MyMessage, 'topic_in', 200)
```

and I publish the message with:

```
self.my_publisher.publish(my_msg)
```

my_msg is built in the following way:

```
payload_bitstream = np.fromstring(my_data, np.uint8)
my_msg = payload_bitstream.tolist()
```

Sadly, I get a TypeError:

```
File "/opt/ros/eloquent/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rclpy/publisher.py", line 68, in publish
    raise TypeError()
TypeError
```

Could you help out with this if you know what I am doing wrong pls?

Thanks in advance,
G.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354644/ros2,-typeerror-when-publishing-custom-message-to-topic/) by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on ROS Answers with karma: 60 on 2020-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The variable you pass to `self.my_publisher.publish()` must be of the same type as the one used to create the publisher, in your case `MyMessage`. So you need to first create an instance of that class:

```
my_msg = MyMessage()
```

and then populate the fields in that message with the desired data:

```
my_msg.data = payload_bitstream.tolist()
```

I would assume you don't even need `.to_list()` in the last line but can assign `payload_bitstream` directly:

```
ms_msg.data = payload_bitstream
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anthares](https://answers.ros.org/users/55473/anthares/) on 2020-06-11**:
Thank you so much! .tolist() is still required. But everything else that you provided was the exact answer and approach.. I mean.. it works: I publish and receive on the subscriber. Thanks so much!!!